# PHP inserting username from one table to another when entering in other data

Tags: php, mysql

i have a bit of a problem im sure you guys can help with here goes.

Im working on a project where by a logged in user enters in some data to a form which then displays the data on another page. The problem im having is im trying to get the 'username' of the the user to be displayed on the data page.

so for example "blah blah blah" submitted by "username"

I have 2 tables 
Members (which has the username)
rideEntry (which has a username2 column, in which i would like the 'username' of the 'Members' table to be stored in)

Im just having trouble capturing the username of the logged in user.

I have tried:

```
  $insert_user = "SELECT * FROM members".
                  "INSERT INTO rideEntry (username2)".
                 "VALUES (username)"; 

  mysql_query($insert_user)
  or die(mysql_error());
```

so far the other data is being entered correctly but the 'username2' is still blank.

Im using session_start(); for the log in procedures

```
 if (!isset($memberID)) {
 $memberID = $_SESSION['memberID'];
  }
```

I feel the problem is that im not being specific enough on the actual username im trying to get as its a logged in user and should be automatic to a point.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

### Thanks

Sorry about it being unclear
Im a novice at php and mysql

I realise now that yes the two username thing is abit silly.  So how do i go about adding the memberID to the rideEntry table?

Here is the code when a user hits submit to their data they just entered

```
<?php


error_reporting(E_ALL | E_WARNING | E_NOTICE);
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);

require_once 'connect_mysql.php';
require_once 'mysql_config.php';
require_once 'view.php';
require_once 'authorize.php';



// Authorize any user, as long as      they're logged in
 authorize_user();

if (!isset($memberID)) {
$memberID = $_SESSION['memberID'];
}

 $upload_dir = HOST_WWW_ROOT ."rides/ride_photos/";
 $image_fieldname = "ride_photos";

$php_errors = array (1 => 'Maximum file size in php.ini exceeded',
                     2 => 'Maximum file size in HTML form exceeded',
                     3 => 'Only part of the file was uploaded',
                     4 => 'No file was selected to upload.');

$date_taken = trim($_REQUEST['date_taken']);
$start_of = trim($_REQUEST['start_of']);
$end_of = trim($_REQUEST['end_of']);
$time_taken = trim($_REQUEST['time_taken']);
$info = trim($_REQUEST['info']);
$place_one = trim($_REQUEST['place_one']);
$place_two = trim($_REQUEST['place_two']);
$place_three = trim($_REQUEST['place_three']);




// Make sure we didn't have an    error uploading the image
($_FILES[$image_fieldname]['error'] == 0)
  or handle_error("the server couldn't upload the image you selected.",
                      $php_errors[$_FILES[$image_fieldname]['error']]);

// Is this file the result of a valid upload?
@is_uploaded_file($_FILES[$image_fieldname]['tmp_name'])
  or handle_error("Unfortunately your request could not be processed",
                  "Uploaded request: file named " .
                  "'{$_FILES[$image_fieldname]['tmp_name']}'");

// is this actually an image?
 @getimagesize($_FILES[$image_fieldname]['tmp_name'])
   or handle_error("you selected a file for your picture " .
                   "that isn't an image.",
                   "{$_FILES[$image_fieldname]['tmp_name']} " .
                   "isn't a valid image file.");

// Name the file uniquely
$now = time();
while (file_exists($upload_filename = $upload_dir . $now .
'-' .
$_FILES[$image_fieldname]['name'])) {
$now++; }



// Finally, move the file to its permanent location
@move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$image_fieldname]['tmp_name'], $upload_filename)
  or handle_error("we had a problem saving your image to " .
                  "its permanent location.",
                  "permissions or related error moving " .
                  "file to {$upload_filename}");

 //Insert data into table
 $insert_sql = sprintf ("INSERT INTO rideEntry ". "(date_taken , start_of, end_of, time_taken, info, place_one, place_two, place_three, ride_photos_path) " .                   
 "VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s') ; ",

    mysql_real_escape_string($date_taken),
    mysql_real_escape_string($start_of),
    mysql_real_escape_string($end_of),
    mysql_real_escape_string($time_taken),
    mysql_real_escape_string($place_one),
    mysql_real_escape_string($place_two),
    mysql_real_escape_string($place_three),
    mysql_real_escape_string($info),
    mysql_real_escape_string($upload_filename));

// Insert the ride into the database
mysql_query($insert_sql)
 or die(mysql_error());

   //redirect
             header("Location:ride_page.php?rideID=".mysql_insert_id());
   exit();
?>
```

Please let me know if more info is needed

Comment: Your question is not clear. You're trying to store the username in 2 different tables in the DB? That's not necessary, store the ID of the user in the second table and use that to determine the username. Anyway, you need to post more code, we can't see your problem.

Comment: your question is too vague....

Comment: I don't understand your question at all. Storing the same data in a database is redundant, you should use foreign keys instead, then use sql joins when you want to retrieve the data... If that's even what you wanted to know

Comment: unclear. Not Getting Anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the others stated, it's hard to understand what you're attempting to accomplish.
From what I understand you simply want to copy the `username` column from the `Member` table into `username2` column of the `rideEntry` table, or retrieve the username somehow.
To copy just `username` over, it looks like you started out in the right direction, but just needed to define the query a little differently.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO rideEntry (username2)
SELECT username FROM Member
WHERE memberID = '" . $memberID. "';
mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

---

While data normalization is practical, it is not always prefered based on application needs. For example recording a `Member.username` at a specific point in time can not be achieved by using a reference to `Member.memberID` in `rideEntry.memberID`. So if you're looking to achieve point in time data, data normalization is not for you.

If you're wanting to use `Member.memberID` as a reference in rideEntry.
You would need to add the `Member.memberID` to your INSERT query.

First you would need to add a `rideEntry.memberID` column as was described in a previous answer.
You could also establish a foreign key reference.

Then just update your `rideEntry` INSERT statement like so.

```
$insert_sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO rideEntry (date_taken , start_of, end_of, time_taken, info, place_one, place_two, place_three, ride_photos_path, memberID) " .                   
 "VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s') ; ",
    mysql_real_escape_string($date_taken),
    mysql_real_escape_string($start_of),
    mysql_real_escape_string($end_of),
    mysql_real_escape_string($time_taken),
    mysql_real_escape_string($place_one),
    mysql_real_escape_string($place_two),
    mysql_real_escape_string($place_three),
    mysql_real_escape_string($info),
    mysql_real_escape_string($upload_filename),
    mysql_real_escape_string($memberID)
);
```

Then you can retrieve the username by performing a JOIN on `Member.memberID` like so

```
$sql = "SELECT t2.username
FROM rideEntry AS t1
JOIN Member AS t2
ON t1.memberID = t2.memberID
WHERE t1.memberID = '". $memberID ."'";

$query = mysql_query($sql);
while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo $result['username'];
}
```

---

Alternatively you can just retrieve the username from the `Member` table and add it to the `rideEntry` INSERT statement.

```
$sql = "SELECT username
FROM Member
WHERE memberID = '". $memberID ."'
LIMIT 1";

$result = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($sql));
$username = $result['username'];

$insert_sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO rideEntry (date_taken , start_of, end_of, time_taken, info, place_one, place_two, place_three, ride_photos_path, username2) " .                   
     "VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s') ; ",
        mysql_real_escape_string($date_taken),
        mysql_real_escape_string($start_of),
        mysql_real_escape_string($end_of),
        mysql_real_escape_string($time_taken),
        mysql_real_escape_string($place_one),
        mysql_real_escape_string($place_two),
        mysql_real_escape_string($place_three),
        mysql_real_escape_string($info),
        mysql_real_escape_string($upload_filename),
        mysql_real_escape_string($username)
);
```

---

And as always I strongly urge you to update to mysqli or PDO with prepared statements to help protect against SQL injection.

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help and for your information.
I used the second option and it works like a charm. I knew there had to be an easy way to query the username, and although its probably not the correct way, for right now and for what im doing its what i need.
Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very open ended, and could have many different answers and techniques. Given the current script, and your question, you have quite a few options.

You could select the username before performing the insert to `rideEntry`, and simply insert that value to `rideEntry.username2`. This causes data duplication and denormalization, and in this case, looks much like a code smell.

To normalize your DB somewhat, you could add a `rideEntry.memberID` column, then select your user record before performing the insert to `rideEntry`, and then inserting that user record's primary key into the `rideEntry.memberID` value. On your subsequent page, you would then select the user record corresponding to `rideEntry.memberID` of the `rideEntry` record that was just inserted, and display the username from the resulting user record.

Since you are passing your user record's primary key around via the `_SESSION` superglobal, you can likely use this value to get both the user record and the `rideEntry` record.

> So how do i go about adding the memberID to the rideEntry table?

Check out the MySQL [ALTER TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html) documentation. The clause you are looking for is `ADD COLUMN`. Some *example* syntax (which may not be syntactically perfect) is as follows:

`ALTER TABLE rideEntry ADD COLUMN user_id INT(11) UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0 AFTER id;`

I would recommend you examine some common PHP frameworks to see how they handle this scenario, as it is quite common to web application programming. You could start with CodeIgniter, Symphony, Laravel, or Yii. After examining how a modern web framework handles passing, inserting, and retrieving data between requests, you will likely want to migrate your application to such a framework.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer and information, will definitely look into those frameworks.